# Should I use Ids for HTML elements in angularjs application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

'Id' of an input element and 'for' of a label, associates label to element and makes label clickable. Also in JQuery/JavaScript it is easy to find the element using ids. But in angularjs there is no use of ids and angularjs rarely need id of an element anywhere , so my first question:

1. Should I have ids to just make label clickable?

Now, most of us would suggest, it depends on my requirements, So I would say, my requirements says, I need to make label clickable. That's why, I am simply putting Ids in all input elements. But another problem comes, when I am trying to create directives for common html templates/sections (e.g. address) to make it reusable. And I am trying to generate dynamic ids for dynamic templates. This becomes complex when my dynamic templates are nested. It also creates problem with ng-required for nested dynamic templates. So other questions are:

1. Is it worth to have dynamic id generation and the complexity, to just make label clickable (which is kind of basic requirement from UX)?
2. Is there any way in angulrjs to get the 'for' functionality of label without having ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to labels you can include the form element inside them:

```
<label>
    Label
    <input type="text"></input>
</label>
```

When you click on the label in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xdcp6/) the input field will be focussed, this would also work for other input tag types.

Comment: I don't think so and can't find anything pointing to the contrary in MDN or w3schools.